# How do I obtain the query results in CodeIgniter as an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm programming an algorithm to do a product search on my web application with CodeIgniter but I have a particular issue; the results of the queries with CodeIgniter Database return an object `object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)`.

What I want to know is how to convert that result to an array of results.

I know that I can use `row_array()` but that gives me the array of the first SQL result and I want an array of the arrays (worth the redundancy) of the SQL results

Also know that I can do a `foreach` with `result_array()` but that option gives me one result at a time and so I have to declare an array variable and add an item at each loop.

So to make myself clear it's something like the `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` function of PDO does but with the CodeIgniter Framework Database Class

Comment: Codeigniter wraps MySQLi, and while newer MySQLi versions [have a `fetch_all()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), Codeigniter [doesn't document a wrapper for it](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).  You could extend it yourself simply, and call `result_array()` in the loop to return the resulting array. Or just define a simple function which receives the result object as a parameter, loops internally and returns the array.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid but thanks, so there is no native method yet...

Comment: I'm not a codeigniter expert but don't know of a native method and can't find one in documentation

Comment: I was looking a lot, and I don't find any, so I made my own function with the loop that I mention on the question, but still feels to me forced :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql_fetch_array command.

```
<?php


mysql_fetch_array($query);


?>
```

This will return the database query into an array based on your query.

Comment: Well maybe if I wasn't working with CodeIgniter Database Class that may work but in that case I'll be using PDO class it's a lot better than working with mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be like

```
$rs = $this->db->query(...);
$array = $rs->result_array();
```

The [reference.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: That just like I posted in the question, just returns an array of the first result inside and array not all the results. But thanks